# How to declare golang dependency versions best in go.mod?

Tags: go, go-modules

The classical way to declare a dependency's version in go mod is via

```golang
require (
    k8s.io/api v0.17.4
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.17.4
    k8s.io/cli-runtime v0.17.0
    k8s.io/client-go v0.17.4
)
```

In the past (go <= 1.12 ?) this has been resolved to timestamp versions, but recently the versions are kept untouched.

However, I've also [seen](https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/91b5ec1d3830d492e643c08992729faac7fcba55/go.mod) this technique to *pin* versions:

```golang
require (
    k8s.io/api v0.17.4
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.17.4
    k8s.io/client-go v11.0.1-0.20190805182717-6502b5e7b1b5+incompatible
    k8s.io/code-generator v0.18.0
    k8s.io/kube-openapi v0.0.0-20191107075043-30be4d16710a
)

replace (
    k8s.io/api => k8s.io/api v0.16.4
    k8s.io/client-go => k8s.io/client-go v0.16.4
    k8s.io/code-generator => k8s.io/code-generator v0.16.4
    k8s.io/kube-openapi => k8s.io/kube-openapi v0.0.0-20190816220812-743ec37842bf
)
```

The question is why would one choose one approach over the other? Is the latter required to resolve conflicting versions coming from transitive dependencies? And if so, why shouldn't one add versions only to the `replace()` clause from the very beginning to be precise (not only in the conflicting case)?

Comment: "In the past (go <= 1.12 ?) this has been resolved to timestamp versions" -- No. Timestamp-based versions are used for packages that don't support go modules. It has nothing to do with the version of Go you're using.

Comment: For example, we generally use `replace` until upstream gets our patch. Via replace, we use our fixed version without any code change and when upstream is updated, we bump version and remove `replace`. It's a solution to overwrite a version as you want. Hope this explanation clarifies its purpose.

Comment: I understand this for replacing the repository or custom fork. And probably for overwriting the version decided by gomod to put into `require()` (it updates that part, too, so its a "shared" text-section (a bit unfortunate). But is it a good practice to use *always* require to be sure that the version chosen by the user is used  ?

Answer (score 0):

A replace is helpful when you want to use a particular version of a dependency in the current module:

- You might want to use that version because it's a fork with modifications you need.

  ```
  require example.com/original v1.0.0
  replace example.com/original => github.com/... v1.0.1
  ```

  (Note: you can replace `v1.0.1` with `master` (or another branch) and it will be replaced with a pseudo-version the next time you `build`/`test`/`mod tidy`.)
- You may not be able to change minor versions of this particular dependency for some reason. Perhaps it requires extra testing to verify behavior or perhaps you've tried newer versions and they don't work.
- You might be making changes to multiple projects, or you have multiple modules in a single repo, and you want to be able to make changes across all of the modules at the same time while developing.

In order for a replace to be meaningful, you need to be *depending* on the module you are *replacing*. You add dependencies in a `go.mod` by using `require`, so you can't *only* use `replace`.

A `replace` is extra work to maintain and replacing everything is not necessary in general. `replace` should be used selectively, when necessary, like in the situations above.

Finally, adding a replace does not make the version selection more "precise." Adding the replace makes it more difficult for a dependency to update. A human will most likely need to go in and say, "Yes, we *do* want to upgrade this dependency," rather than let Minimum Version Selection decide when to upgrade a dependency, which could happen accidentally without a human noticing. As noted above, that could be bad for some projects.