# Can't sync Go package from a parallel directory

Tags: go, go-modules

This should be a simple matter in Go 1.14.2 but for some reason it's not. I have the following project layout...

```
go
└── src
│   └── github.com
│   │   └── folder
│   │   │   ├── my-first-project
│   │   │   └── my-second-project
```

In the main file of `my-second-project` my import statement contains the usual libraries, plus...

```
import (
    // standard libraries
    "github.com/folder/my-first-project/module/sub-module"
)
```

When I try to sync so I can import that submodule, Go attempts to download it from GitHub instead of looking in the local folder, which means it's unable to find this project. However, my `GOPATH` is set to the go folder and the go.mod file in `my-second-project` begins with...

```
module github.com/folder/my-second_project
```

... so I cannot figure out what I could possibly be missing that makes this import so difficult. I'm using fully qualified references, but for some reason, I can't get two projects living side by side to talk to each other. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: **Either** use GOPATH Mode or Modules mode, you cannot mix them. When in Modules mode use a replace directive.

Answer (score 0):

When using Modules, Go does not look in `GOPATH`. Modules use a read only cache of modules so they don't need to be downloaded every time you build.

If you are developing a module that isn't published yet, you can use a `replace` directive to point to the local directory where the other dependency is located.

See [How to declare golang dependency versions best in go.mod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005883/how-to-declare-golang-dependency-versions-best-in-go-mod/62388554#62388554) for some additional information about when you would use `replace`.